# Existence for the limit of a function

Tags: calculus

Let $f : (0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded and differentiable function, such that $f(x)f'(x) \geq \cos x$ for all $x > 0$. Does $\lim\limits_{x\to 1} f(x)$ exist?

Comment: $2f(x)f'(x)=2cosx=>f^2(x)=2sinx+c$

Comment: Is that supposed to be the limit as $x \to 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\cos x>0$ for $0<x<1$, $f$ (and $f'$) cannot be zero in $(0,1)$, so $f$ and $f'$ never change sign. Therefore $f$ is monotonic. Since $f$ is also bounded, the limit exists.